# Hosting .net Core 2.0 WebAPI on IIS returns 502.5 Process Faiure

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

When I publish my .net Core 2.0 app to IIS I recieve a HTTP Error 502.5 Process Failure.

I have read the [HOST ASP.NET Core...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) Several times without beeing able solving my problem.

I can start the app from cli "dotnet AppWebApi.dll" but i Can't access the app with the command "http://localhost:5000" Receive "WebPage cannot be found"

My best guess so far, is that the problem are related to hosting the .Net Core WebAPI as a SubWeb to an non .netCore WEB.

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AppWebAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\AppWebApi.log" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I Know similar questions has been asked before, but none of these has so far solved my problem, so I hope to get some new impulses.

Comment: Have you successfully hosted other ASP.NET Core (1.x or 2.0) applications on that machine?

Comment: No this is my first attemp to make an .NetCore WebAPI. I have used .net 4.5 webapi before with success.

Comment: I'll be back in a bit and look more deeply, but be sure that you installed the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle and restarted IIS.  What type of deploy are you doing?

Comment: Yes the .Net Core Windows Server Hosting bundle "DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe" is installed, and I did restart the iiS. I publish trough VS 2017

Comment: I experienced something similar before. I had the application compiled to 32-bit, but the server was 64-bit. Once I compiled the application to match the server architecture, the application worked. Worth checking into.

Comment: "publish through VS2017" includes several options. :) Azure, IIS Web, FTP, Folder, ...?  Anything in the logs?

Comment: @R. Richards I. had Target set to Any CPU. Setting it specific to 64-bit did not make any difference.

Comment: @Alan Larimer I'm not shure witch logs you are thinking of. I'm publishing to an on premisis IIS server, using similar settings as I have ben using many times before, and the publishing seems to be succesfully completed.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I had to change the `RuntimeIdentifier` value in the *.csproj* file to get this to work, changing the target didn't seem make any difference. I think it defaulted to `win7-x86`, and I changed it to something compatible with the server version I deployed to. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) for possible values.

Comment: @R. Ricards It definitively made a difference to the publishing, as it now publishes all DLLs and other files. Unfortunately, it did not make any difference one the error. I guess that this "RuntimeIdentifier" is for Self-Contained Deployment (SCD)?. while I'm trying to use Framework Contained Deployment (FDD)